# Можно ли средствами php вытащить число из такой строки?

Tags: php

Например значение строки `$a = "абв351abc"`, можно ли только средствами php вытащить числовое значение из этой строки?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "средствами php". `preg_math('/(\d+)/','абв351abc',$match); print $match[1]` подходит под определение "средства php" ?

Comment: А с переменной вместо строки будет preg_math('/(\d+)/',$name,$match); print $match[1]?

Comment: Будет конечно. php как бы все равно, строка где то или переменная ее содержащая

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться!

Comment: Да, можно, вытаскивайте. )

Comment: @Mike функция preg_math() - это что-то новенькое! :)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть фильтры :

```
echo(filter_var('asdasd0755asdasdasd', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));//0755
echo(filter_var('a13sdasd07.55asd', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT , FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION)); //1307.55
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос – **Можно**.

Расширенный ответ на вопрос (хотя вопросы надо уметь задавать). Вытащить цифру из строки можно например регулярным выражением.

```
$a = "абв351abc123"; // входная строка
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $a, $match); // ищем все вхождения чисел от 1 цифры и далее
if(isset($match[0])) { // проверяем, если ли совпадения
    foreach($match[0] as $number) {
        var_dump((int) $number); // приводим в числовому типу
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если число одно, можно просто удалить буквы:

```
$num=(int)preg_replace("/[A-zА-я]/","","абВ351abC");
print ("<br>num=$num");
```

Результат:

```
num=351
```

Если число может иметь знак и десятичную точку, тогда:

```
preg_match_all("/[+-]*[0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*/", "абВ-351.5abC", $match);
$num = $match[0][0]+0;    
printf ("<br>num = $num");
```

Результат:

```
num = -351.5
```

Comment: 26 букв в разных регистрах против 10 цифр. А если еще и знаки препинания и иные символы полезут? Так не проще ли только цифры и вытащить?

Comment: @Vitalts Числа могут содержать десятичную точку, знаки и разделители групп цифр. Хотя с обозначением степени e вопросы возникнут у всех.

Comment: @Vitalts Проверка букв, идущих подряд - это пара условий. Кстати, в моём первом варианте несколько символов фудаляется вместе с буквами (есть разрыв между Z и a). Но если нужны не только int, то точнее второй вариант.